# Adding up several lists horizontally

Tags: java, algorithm, list, loops

I have a list of objects. Each object has a list. What I want to do is to add these objects horizontally to a new list so that it looks like this:

[image]

At the moment I am struggling with a proper algorithm, so I wrote this little test program:

```
public class testClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<Double> list3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<List<Double>> objectList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();

        //add data
        list1.add(1.0);
        list1.add(2.0);
        list1.add(3.0);
        list1.add(4.0);
        list1.add(5.0);
        list1.add(6.0);
        list1.add(7.0);

        list2.add(1.0);
        list2.add(2.0);
        list2.add(3.0);
        list2.add(4.0);
        list2.add(5.0);
        list2.add(6.0);
        list2.add(7.0);

        list3.add(1.0);
        list3.add(2.0);
        list3.add(3.0);
        list3.add(4.0);
        list3.add(5.0);
        list3.add(6.0);
        list3.add(7.0);

        objectList.add(list1);
        objectList.add(list2);
        objectList.add(list3);

        double result = 0.0;
        List<Double> resultList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objectList.get(i).size(); j++) {
                result =+ objectList.get(i).get(j);
            resultList.add(result);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(resultList.toString());
    }

}
```

However, what I am currently getting is:

`[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]`

Any recommendations on how to fix that to get the desired output from the picture?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

Changing to `+=` operator I am getting:

`[1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0, 15.0, 21.0, 28.0, 29.0, 31.0, 34.0, 38.0, 43.0, 49.0, 56.0, 57.0, 59.0, 62.0, 66.0, 71.0, 77.0, 84.0]`

The list size has tripled. How to add the elements horizontally?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder What do you mean?

Comment: code you have mentioned `=+` but in question you mentioned `+=`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder yes but I do not changed the code at all. I only changed the `update section`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done a very minor mistake. There is no operator like `=+`. It is `+=` instead.

```
result += objectList.get(i).get(j);
```

What `result =+ objectList.get(i).get(j);` will do is assign the positive(`+`) of `objectList.get(i).get(j)` to the result.

And also, you have not added anything to `resultList` and that is why it prints a empty list. You need to add some data into this list before printing it out.

*Edit:* To add them horizontally, you don't need a double `for` loop at all. A single for loop should do.

```
for (int j = 0; j < list1.size(); j++) { // assuming all lists are of same size
    result = list1.get(j) + list2.get(j) + list3.get(j);
    resultList.add(result);
}
```

*Edit2:* Since you've a lot of lists(38, 000 of them), you can try this approach. You need to add the result to the result set after each inner `for` loop completes(addition of one row of elements) and not after every addition(addition of each element) and then reset the value to `0.0`. This also explains why the no. of elements in the `resultList` tripled.

```
double result = 0.0;
List<Double> resultList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int j = 0; j < objectList.get(0).size(); j++) { // assuming all lists are of same size
    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        result += objectList.get(i).get(j);
    }
    resultList.add(result);
    result = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However I still do not get the results I wish. Please see my update!

Comment: Thx for your answer! Basically I would also implement it like that. However I have a program were I have more thatn 38000 lists and this is not possible at all...

Comment: Wont result = list1.get(j) + list2.get(j) + list3.get(j); add the sum of the 3 values to 1 list spot? Instead of adding a value to each spot horizontaly?

Comment: Yep indeed this would do the job however. having from list1 to list 38000 I cannot do that by listing them...

Comment: OK I tried the second update out. However I get: `[28.0, 56.0, 84.0]` which is basically adding each list vertically up...

Comment: @user2051347 - I tried it out the new edit 2 and it worked for me. Check it out! :)